# 535 Incorrect authentication data, cpanel

Tags: smtp, cpanel

I've got this error while using my smtp server (smtp.gmail.com)

```
> SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "535 Incorrect authentication data " 
> SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect
> authentication data  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""  SMTP ->
> get_lines(): $str is "250 Reset OK "  SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is
> "250 Reset OK "  SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Reset OK  SMTP Error: Could
> not authenticate.
```

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps is set to on

Still the same issue until I deselect Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak) in the cpanel.

it seems to add those rules in the iptables when it's ON (not working for me):

> -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner mailman -j ACCEPT 
>   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner mail -j ACCEPT 
>   -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner cpanel -j ACCEPT 
>   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT

It works well when set to off but I'd like to understand why it doesn't want to work with the normal settings?

It seems my apache is using nobody:nobody but even if I add those 2 lines it won't work:

> -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner nobody -j ACCEPT 
>   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner nobody -j ACCEPT

I'm using TLS 587.

Comment: Problem it's possible for you like connect to gmail account with security activated and you think it's no activate. Recheck. For other replies, if Cphulk, firewall not cause. Simply.  `"535 Incorrect authentication data "`it's a reply for Remote SMTP Server

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Oo_y117aVGU/discussion

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be the cPHulk (login blocking software). So adding the external IP of the server's cPHulk blacklist. The solution is to add the IP to the cPHulk whitelist may resolve the problem.

Comment: Where you see Cphulk in action?

Comment: Thank you for this. I was ripping my hair out trying to figure out why our emails on a 6 year old server started getting blocked from another server.